# c++ boolean compound assignment thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

As pointed out below, none of this is thread safe because `anyTrue` is not atomic, even though it may behave atomically on some hardware:

```
#include <thread>

bool blah() {
    return true; // or false
}

int main()
{
    bool anyTrue = false;

    // I think foo should be thread safe:
    auto foo = [&] {
        if (blah()) {
            anyTrue = true;
        }
    };

    // but I'm not confident about bar:
    auto bar = [&] {
        anyTrue &= blah();
    };

    // parallel foo:
    std::thread t1 (foo);
    std::thread t2 (foo);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    // parallel bar:
    std::thread t3 (bar);
    std::thread t4 (bar);
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}
```

If I make `anyTrue` `atomic` it no longer compiles because `atomic` has no `operator&=`:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

bool blah() {
    return true; // or false
}

int main()
{
    std::atomic< bool > anyTrue (false);

    // I think foo should be thread safe:
    auto foo = [&] {
        if (blah()) {
            anyTrue = true;
        }
    };

    // but I'm not confident about bar:
    auto bar = [&] {
        anyTrue &= blah(); // error: no viable overloaded '&='
    };

    // parallel foo:
    std::thread t1 (foo);
    std::thread t2 (foo);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    // parallel bar:
    std::thread t3 (bar);
    std::thread t4 (bar);
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}
```

Comment: why do you think the first one is thread safe? You write the same variable from two different threads without any synchronization, what is safe about that?

Comment: None of them is thread safe.

Comment: @manni66 neither thread reads anyTrue and the write order doesn't matter.

Comment: `operator&=` needs to read and write, no?

Comment: "For people saying foo isn't thread safe, I think it is:" .... you are wrong

Comment: @tobi303  Yes, but the end result is the same in my tests, but that may be just luck I suppose, hence the question.

Comment: @tobi303  I very well might be wrong, can you explain why?

Comment: [Two unsynchronized writes to the same memory location constitute a data race](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races). Data race exhibits undefined behavior. It doesn't matter if both writes actually assign the same value - the behavior is still undefined. This alone is sufficient to render both `foo` and `bar` unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no thread safety at all here:

1. `std::rand` is neither re-entrant nor thread safe. In fact, it maintains an internal seed, so you're in deep water here.
2. `&=` requires a read, modify, then a write. That's not threadsafe.
3. Assignment `=` might not be thread-safe (e.g. two threads might be writing to the same memory at the same time, with undefined results.) This is a good old-fashioned *data race*. Who is to say you don't have a really fat `bool` on your platform?

Comment: ah i just used stand::rand for convenience but you're right, i'll fix that.

Comment: @atb: no need, although `std::rand` is the elephant in the room here.

Comment: I agree with 1 and 2 but not 3.

Comment: @atb: Interesting. What does the C++ standard say about `sizeof(bool)`?

Comment: You're right, I was under the false impression that bool was atomic, switching to be explicitly 'atomic' makes 'bar' fail to compile.

Comment: IMHO bool was one of the worst things to ever enter the C++ standard.